# Microsoft bot error - Exception: invalid need: expected Call, have Poll

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, botframework

I keep getting this error and I don't know how to fix it: Exception: invalid need: expected Call, have Poll

```
            PromptDialog.Text(context, setEmail, "What is the contact's email? "); 
            PromptDialog.Text(context, setPhone, "What is the contact's phone number? ");


    private async Task setPhone(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        this.contact1.Phone = await result;
        ReturnContact(context, contact1);

    }

    private async Task setEmail(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        this.contact1.Email = await result;
        ReturnContact(context, contact1);
    }
```

the prompt dialogs are part of a different method. How do I prompt the user twice in a row without getting this error?

Comment: let me know if you need more info

Answer (score 2):

`PromptDialog.Text` was not designed to be called twice, because you need two different answers from a user, so in terms of botframework it is like two separate "transactions".

Rather than making a double call you need to create a cascade of calls, where you initiate the Phone question from the Email question handler:

```
[Serializable]
public class SomeDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync); 
    }

    private async Task OnPhoneSet(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        var res = await result;
    }

    private async Task OnEmailSet(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        var res = await result;
        PromptDialog.Text(context, OnPhoneSet, "What is the contact's phone number? ");
    }

    public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
    {
        var message = await argument;

        PromptDialog.Text(context, OnEmailSet, "What is the contact's email? ");
    }
}
```

The workflow is like the following:

1. User initiates a dialog for the first time. Callstack: `StartAsync` ->  `MessageReceivedAsync` -> `PromptDialog.Text(context, OnEmailSet)`. Now dialog is waiting for Email posted
2. User posts Email. Callstack: `OnEmailSet` -> `PromptDialog.Text(context, OnPhoneSet`. Now dialog is waiting for Phone posted
3. User posts Phone. Callstack: `OnPhoneSet`. On `OnPhoneSet` you'll do further actions, for example you can close dialog using `Context.Done` or something.